# What sort of projects should I use Go for?

Tags: programming-languages, go

The [Go language](http://golang.org/) is a new programming language from Google. It is still in an experimental phase and I am having trouble figuring out how stable it is. What sort of projects would you risk using Go for?

Comment: I do not understand the close-votes given the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712172/whats-your-take-on-the-programming-language-go. Mine is a lot more specific.

Comment: They were both closed for the same reason, so what's not to understand? And a question about what "you" would do, where "you" is an unspecified person, is the opposite of specific. Stick with questions for which an objective answer is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you said, it is still an experimental programming language so I would only use it for experimental projects, for now. The implementation is still young but more importantly the ecosystem around it is also not very mature. In other words you'll probably have a hard time finding frameworks and libraries to help speed up your development and may end up needing to code a lot more than if you had chosen a more mature language.